# Convert stdClass object with multiple entries/value to array in PHP

Tags: php, object, stdclass

I fetch $pmpro_levels from postmeta as:

when i try print_r($pmpro_levels); I have array like this:

```
$pmpro_levels=Array
(
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => PREMIUM
            [description] => <h4 style="text-align: center"><strong>3 Mois</strong></h4>
<p style="text-align: center">7€ /mois</p>
<p style="text-align: center"><span style="color: #000000">soit 0,70€ par jour</span></p>
             
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => GOLD
            [description] => <h4 style="text-align: center"><strong>6 Mois</strong></h4>
<p style="text-align: center">6€ /mois</p>
<p style="text-align: center"><span style="color: #000000">soit 0,20€ par jour</span></p>
            
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => MINI
            [description] => <h4 style="text-align: center"><strong>1 Mois</strong></h4>
<p style="text-align: center">10€ /mois</p>
<p style="text-align: center"><span style="color: #000000">soit 0,33€ par jour</span></p>
            ));
```

and i dont know how to traverse it, and how could I get array like this

```
Array
(
    [2]  => string data not object


    [3] => string data  not object


    [5] => string data  not object

)
```

Any idea how can I do this? I would like to have an array without object. Do we have to use jason? I a newbie in PHP.

Comment: Cast object to array like (array)$obj

Comment: What string data do you want?  There is id, name and description.

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Comment: yes , i found the issue by another way. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```php
$newArray = [];
foreach($pmpro_levels as $level) {
    $newArray[] = get_object_vars($level);
}
```

or using array_map:

```php
$newArray = array_map(function ($level) {return get_object_vars($level);}, $pmpro_levels);
```

If you want to convert an array to stdClass object you can typecast it to `object` like so:

```php
$myArray = [ 'title' => 'My title', 'description' => 'Some description' ];
$myObject = (object)$myArray;
```